# Jquery mobile .collapsible function giving "object has no method collapsible"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-collapsible

Jquery mobile .collapsible function giving "object has no method collapsible" when i try to use it for dynamically adding collapsible elements to menu.

Here is my code:

```
var template=$('#template #c').clone();
template.attr('id','c_'+value.A);
template.attr('data-role','collapsible');
template.find('h3 a span .ui-btn-text').html(value.B);
$('#menu').append(template);
$('#c_'+value.A).show();
$('#c_'+value.A).collapsible();
```

The template is a collapsible element layout

```
<div class="template" id="template">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="c" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" data-inset="false">
    <h3 id="c_name">dsa</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
        <li id="item"><a href="#">adsd</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /collapsible -->
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me ???

Comment: use `.trigger('create');` http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/6Jj8k/

Comment: @Omar i even tried this and its not working :/

Comment: Are you appending new collapsible, or doing changes to the collapsible? can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes.. I'm cloning a template collapsible, editing it and appending it to the container div. The template collapsible is working fine but the cloned ones are not working

Answer (score 0):

try following:

From

```
$('#c_'+value.A).show();  
$('#c_'+value.A).collapsible();
```

To

```
$('#c_'+value.A).slideDown();
$('#c_'+value.A).slideUp();
```

Comment: This one makes the collapsible element slide Up and is not working... its not making the list under the collapsible element work

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$('#c_'+value.A).collapsible();
```

use

```
$( "#c_"+value.A ).trigger( "expand" ); // to expand collapsible
```